# Get rid of if-else ladder when creating JPA criteria query based on sort/filter fields of LazyDataModel

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm using,

- JPA 2.0
- Mojarra 2.1.9
- JSF component library, Primefaces 3.5.
- MySQL 5.6.11

I have a table in MySQL database named `state_table` with three columns as an example.

- state_id (BigInt)
- state_name (Varchar)
- country_id (BigInt)

`state_id` is a auto-generated primary key and `country_id` is a foreign key that references a primary key of the `country` table.

---

This table is mapped by its corresponding entity class named `StateTable` and the data held by this table are displayed in a Primefaces `DataTable`, `<p:dataTable>...</p:dataTable>`.

The `DataTable` column header contains a clickable sort area, `<div>` for each column with a sort direction for sorting, when this area is clicked, a String, either `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` representing the sort order is rendered and a text box for filtering (searching) in which a user enters a search item for each column.

---

So ultimately, what I get in JSF managed bean is a List of type `java.util.List<org.primefaces.model.SortMeta>` representing sort orders of the columns of the `DataTable` that a user wishes.

And a Map of type `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>` representing the search column names as keys and search items of the corresponding columns as values (a search item is entered by a user in a text box on the column header of each column of `DataTable`).

---

In short, I use `List<SortMeta>` for sorting and `Map<String, String>` for filtering/searching.

My code in one of the DAOs to get a list of rows after sorting and filtering is as follows.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<StateTable> getList(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String>filters)
{
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<StateTable> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(StateTable.class);
    Metamodel metamodel=entityManager.getMetamodel();
    EntityType<StateTable> entityType = metamodel.entity(StateTable.class);
    Root<StateTable>root=criteriaQuery.from(entityType);
    Join<StateTable, Country> join = null;

    //Sorting

    List<Order> orders=new ArrayList<Order>();

    if(multiSortMeta!=null&&!multiSortMeta.isEmpty())
    {
        for(SortMeta sortMeta:multiSortMeta)
        {
            if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("stateId"))
            {
                orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)):criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)));
            }
            else if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("stateName"))
            {
                orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(StateTable_.stateName)):criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateName)));
            }
            else if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("country.countryName")) // Yes, Primefaces DataTable renders this ugly name in case of a nested property representing a foreign key relationship.
            {
                join = root.join(StateTable_.countryId, JoinType.INNER);
                orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(join.get(Country_.countryName)):criteriaBuilder.desc(join.get(Country_.countryName)));
            }
        }
    }

    //Filtering/searching

    List<Predicate>predicates=new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    if(filters!=null&&!filters.isEmpty())
    {
        for(Entry<String, String>entry:filters.entrySet())
        {
            if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("stateId"))
            {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(StateTable_.stateId), Long.parseLong(entry.getValue())));
            }
            else if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("stateName"))
            {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(StateTable_.stateName), "%"+entry.getValue()+"%"));
            }
            else if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("country.countryName"))// Yes, Primefaces DataTable renders this ugly name in case of a nested property representing a foreign key relationship.
            {
                if(join==null)
                {
                    join = root.join(StateTable_.countryId, JoinType.INNER);
                }
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(join.get(Country_.countryName), "%"+entry.getValue()+"%"));
            }
        }
    }

    if(predicates!=null&&!predicates.isEmpty())
    {
        criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }

    if(orders!=null&&!orders.isEmpty())
    {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(orders);
    }
    else
    {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)));
    }
    TypedQuery<StateTable> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFirstResult(first).setMaxResults(pageSize);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();        
}
```

This works as expected but as it can be noticed, the `if-else if` ladder inside the `foreach` loop can contain many conditional checks as the number of columns in a database table are increased.

Each column requires a conditional check for both sorting and searching. Is there an efficient way to get rid of these conditional checks that can ultimately remove or at least minimize this `if-else if` ladder?

P.S. In case of country, I'm doing sorting and searching on `countryName` (which is available in the parent table `country`) rather than `countryId`. Hence, I'm using `Join`, in this case.

Comment: Not sure what you're concretely asking related to JSF/PrimeFaces, but did you look at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf?

Comment: For **sorting** and **filtering**, this `if-else-if` ladder may be tedious to maintain for every column, if there are more than 10 (or so) columns in the database. I'm using `LazyDataModel<T>` though.

Comment: Hmm, after reading your question twice more, it looks like you're already using it. After all, your whole question is confusing as the concrete question ultimately boils down to be unrelated to JSF/PF/JPA (reimplement Java if-else ladder using some design pattern which allows better scaling). The preface is perhaps nice, but just unnecessary.

Comment: JSF/PF/JPA might have some mechanisms (that hopefully I don't know) that can help reduce/remove this `if-else-if` construct in a better and efficient way.

Comment: Okay. JSF/PF at least not. JSF has no role here. PF just offers the basic API here. JPA Criteria API is indeed a pain if you want to go a bit dynamic. I can answer in plain Java terms how to refactor the code as such that you can get rid of that ladder, but this kind of questions actually fit better at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: [This](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/27659/23481) is the same (duplicate) unanswered question on codereview I posted hoping that there might be some chances to get answer(s) there.

Comment: Okay. Is there any technical reason that you use `SingularAttribute` instead of plain strings? E.g. does `root.get("stateId")` also work just fine for you? If so, that would simplify it a lot more as exactly those values are already supplied in the list/map of sort/filter fields.

Comment: There is no reason other than compile-time type check ([type safe criteria query](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-typesafejpa/) using Metamodel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you drop the usage of `SingularAttribute` values and you make sure that the caller calls the method with exactly the desired column names in sort/filter fields, then you could simplify it a lot more by just reusing the iterated sort/filter field as column name without the need for an if/else check on the field in order to specify the right column name (which is after all actually identical to the sort/filter field name).

Essentially, you don't need those `equalsIgnoreCase()` checks in `if-else` ladder at all. As to case sensitivity, if the caller is doing it wrong, just fix it over there instead of being too forgiving on caller's mistakes.

Here's how you could refactor it then:

```
/**
 * @throws NullPointerException When <code>multiSortMeta</code> or <code>filters</code> argument is null.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<?> getList(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String> filters) {
    // ...

    Root<StateTable> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityType);
    Join<StateTable, Country> join = root.join(StateTable_.countryId, JoinType.INNER);

    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

    for (SortMeta sortMeta : multiSortMeta) {
        String[] sortField = sortMeta.getSortField().split("\\.", 2);
        Path<Object> path = sortField.length == 1 ? root.get(sortField[0]) : join.get(sortField[1]);
        orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING 
            ? criteriaBuilder.asc(path) 
            : criteriaBuilder.desc(path));
    }

    List<Predicate>predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    for (Entry<String, String> filter : filters.entrySet()) {
        String[] filterField = filter.getKey().split("\\.", 2);
        Path path = filterField.length == 1 ? root.get(filterField[0]): join.get(filterField[1]);
        predicates.add(filter.getValue().matches("[0-9]+") 
            ? criteriaBuilder.equal(path, Long.valueOf(filter.getValue()))
            : criteriaBuilder.like(path, "%" + filter.getValue() + "%"));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that I also modified the method to not accept `null` as sort and filter meta, so that you can safely trim out all those null checks. Those empty checks are unnecessary as the `for` loop won't iterate anyway if it's empty. Also note that the filtering uses `CriteriaBuilder#equal()` if a numeric input is given, otherwise it uses `like()`. I'm not sure if that covers all your cases, you may want to finetune that more.

You can if necessary refactor the obtaining of `Path` even more with the following helper method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static Path<?> getPath(String field, Root root, Join join) {
    String[] fields = field.split("\\.", 2);
    return fields.length == 1 ? root.get(fields[0]): join.get(fields[1]);
}
```