# JPA Dynamic Order By with Criteria API

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have the below code snippet for dynamic sorting using JPA Criteria API

```
Root<Employee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Employee);
Join<Employee, Project> joinProject = 
        root.join(Employee_.projectList, JoinType.LEFT);

if (sortDirection.equals("asc")) {               
criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(sortField)));
```

If I am passing an attribute of `Employee` entity to order by statement, it works without any hitch, however if an attribute of `Project` entity is passed to order by statement, exception is thrown stating that

```
The attribute [projectName] is not present in the managed type
```

because `projectName` is an attribute of `Project`entity  which is joined with Employee using `joinProject`. In order by statement I am using `root.get(sortField)`. if it is `joinProject.get(sortField)`, it would work fine when attributes of `Project` are being passed to order by statement.

My questions are

How could I modify my `Order By` statement in order to cater all the attributes which being passed?

Do I need to conditionally check which attribute and accordingly use if conditions or are there better ways of doing this?

Appreciate insight into this.

Comment: You are constructing a dynamic query in that case the code would look a bit uglier and be maintenance-unfriendly somewhat but that happens because it is a dynamic query but at least it is better than writing dynamic queries without using the criteria API which results in awkward string concatenation. I use a `switch...case` construct inside an enhanced `for` loop. The application client supplies a `Map<String, Object>` of filters (search criteria) and / or a `Map<String, String>` of sort orders.

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18540920/1391249) but you will then have to sacrifice the JPA static meta model and concentrate on string based expressions / paths.

Answer (score 4):

A specific approach for a simple scenario (predetermined one-level only joins) may be something like this:

```
    Root<Employee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
    Join<Employee, Project> joinProject = root.join(Employee_.projectList, JoinType.LEFT);

    Class<?> baseClass = fieldTypeMap.get(sortField);
    From<?, ?> from;
    if(baseClass == Employee.class)
    {
        from = root;
    }
    else if(baseClass == Project.class)
    {
        from = joinTeam;
    }
    else ...

    Expression<?> expr = from.get(sortField);

    if(sortDirection.equals("asc")) 
    {               
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(expr));
    }

    ...
```

where `fieldTypeMap` is something like:

```
private final static Map<String, Class<?>> fieldTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
static {
    fieldTypeMap.put("employeeName", Employee.class);
    fieldTypeMap.put("projectName", Project.class);
    ...
}
```

**However, this is quick and dirty, ugly and unmaintainable.**

If you want a generic approach, things may get a bit complex.

Personally, I'm using my own classes built on top of `EntityManager`, `CriteriaBuilder` and Metamodel, which provides dynamic filtering and multi-sorting features.
But something like this should be meaningful enough:

```
protected static List<Order> buildOrderBy(CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<?> root, List<SortMeta> sortList)
{
    List<Order> orderList = new LinkedList<>();

    for(SortMeta sortMeta : sortList)
    {
        String sortField = sortMeta.getSortField();
        SortOrder sortOrder = sortMeta.getSortOrder();

        if(sortField == null || sortField.isEmpty() || sortOrder == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        Expression<?> expr = getExpression(root, sortField);

        if(sortOrder == SortOrder.ASCENDING)
        {
            orderList.add(builder.asc(expr));
        }
        else if(sortOrder == SortOrder.DESCENDING)
        {
            orderList.add(builder.desc(expr));
        }
    }

    return orderList;
}

protected static Expression<?> getExpression(Root<?> root, String sortField)
{
    ManagedType<?> managedType = root.getModel();
    From<?, Object> from = (From<?, Object>) root;

    String[] elements = sortField.split("\\.");
    for(String element : elements)
    {
        Attribute<?, ?> attribute = managedType.getAttribute(element);
        if(attribute.getPersistentAttributeType() == PersistentAttributeType.BASIC)
        {
            return from.get(element);
        }

        from = from.join(element, JoinType.LEFT);
        managedType = EntityUtils.getManagedType(from.getJavaType());
    }

    return from;
}
```

This way the join is based on sort field, which is now a dotted-path-expr like "projectList.name" or "office.responsible.age"

---

```
public static <X> ManagedType<X> getManagedType(Class<X> clazz)
{
    try
    {
        return getMetamodel().managedType(clazz);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static Metamodel getMetamodel()
{
    return getEntityManagerFactory().getMetamodel();
}

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory()
{
    try
    {
        return InitialContext.doLookup("java:module/persistence/EntityManagerFactory");
    }
    catch(NamingException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

to make it work on a webapp, you have to declare contextual references on web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <display-name>my_app_name</display-name>

    ...

    <persistence-context-ref>
        <persistence-context-ref-name>java:module/persistence/EntityManager</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>my_pu_name</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>

    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>java:module/persistence/EntityManagerFactory</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>my_pu_name</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>
</web-app>
```

---

**update**

I don't know about how EclipseLink handles grouping, but also Hibernate does not perform joins (actually, conditions on joins) correctly in some case.

In example, when all these conditions are met:

- querying an entity (as Root/From) that is part of a class hierarchy (and not a leaf) based on SINGLE_TABLE
- joining/getting a property of a subclass
- joining/getting by property name (String) instead of Attribute

To workaround the issue I always resolve property name to an Attribute and reuse joins already "walked" (*did I say things may get complicated?*):

```
public class MetaDescriptor extends BusinessObject implements Serializable, MemberEx, ColumnDescriptor
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @BusinessKey
    protected final Attribute<?, ?> attribute;

    @BusinessKey
    protected final MetaDescriptor parent;

    protected List<MetaDescriptor> childList;

    protected final Type<?> elementType;

    ...

    protected MetaDescriptor(Attribute<?, ?> attribute, MetaDescriptor parent)
    {
        this.attribute = attribute;
        this.parent = parent;

        if(attribute instanceof SingularAttribute)
        {
            SingularAttribute<?, ?> singularAttribute = (SingularAttribute<?, ?>) attribute;
            elementType = singularAttribute.getType();
        }
        else if(attribute instanceof PluralAttribute)
        {
            PluralAttribute<?, ?, ?> pluralAttribute = (PluralAttribute<?, ?, ?>) attribute;
            elementType = pluralAttribute.getElementType();
        }
        else
        {
            elementType = null;
        }
    }

    public static MetaDescriptor getDescriptor(ManagedType<?> managedType, String path)
    {
        return getDescriptor(managedType, path, null);
    }

    public static MetaDescriptor getDescriptor(From<?, ?> from, String path)
    {
        if(from instanceof Root)
        {
            return getDescriptor(((Root<?>) from).getModel(), path);
        }

        return getDescriptor(from.getJavaType(), path);
    }

    public static MetaDescriptor getDescriptor(Class<?> clazz, String path)
    {
        ManagedType<?> managedType = EntityUtils.getManagedType(clazz);
        if(managedType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return getDescriptor(managedType, path);
    }

    private static MetaDescriptor getDescriptor(ManagedType<?> managedType, String path, MetaDescriptor parent)
    {
        if(path == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Entry<String, String> slice = StringUtilsEx.sliceBefore(path, '.');
        String attributeName = slice.getKey();

        Attribute<?, ?> attribute;
        if("class".equals(attributeName))
        {
            attribute = new ClassAttribute<>(managedType);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                attribute = managedType.getAttribute(attributeName);
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                Class<?> managedClass = managedType.getJavaType();

                // take only if it is unique
                attribute = StreamEx.of(EntityUtils.getMetamodel().getManagedTypes())
                    .filter(x -> managedClass.isAssignableFrom(x.getJavaType()))
                    .flatCollection(ManagedType::getDeclaredAttributes)
                    .filterBy(Attribute::getName, attributeName)
                    .limit(2)
                    .collect(Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> null))
                    .orElse(null);

                if(attribute == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        MetaDescriptor descriptor = new MetaDescriptor(attribute, parent);

        String remainingPath = slice.getValue();
        if(remainingPath.isEmpty())
        {
            return descriptor;
        }

        Type<?> elementType = descriptor.getElementType();
        if(elementType instanceof ManagedType)
        {
            return getDescriptor((ManagedType<?>) elementType, remainingPath, descriptor);
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Expression<T> getExpression(CriteriaBuilder builder, From<?, ?> from)
    {
        From<?, Object> parentFrom = getParentFrom(from);

        if(attribute instanceof ClassAttribute)
        {
            return (Expression<T>) parentFrom.type();
        }

        if(isSingular())
        {
            return parentFrom.get((SingularAttribute<Object, T>) attribute);
        }

        return getJoin(parentFrom, JoinType.LEFT);
    }

    private <X, T> From<X, T> getParentFrom(From<?, ?> from)
    {
        return OptionalEx.of(parent)
            .map(x -> x.getJoin(from, JoinType.LEFT))
            .select(From.class)
            .orElse(from);
    }

    public <X, T> Join<X, T> getJoin(From<?, ?> from, JoinType joinType)
    {
        From<?, X> parentFrom = getParentFrom(from);

        Join<X, T> join = (Join<X, T>) StreamEx.of(parentFrom.getJoins())
            .findAny(x -> Objects.equals(x.getAttribute(), attribute))
            .orElseGet(() -> buildJoin(parentFrom, joinType));

        return join;
    }

    private <X, T> Join<X, T> buildJoin(From<?, X> from, JoinType joinType)
    {
        if(isSingular())
        {
            return from.join((SingularAttribute<X, T>) attribute, joinType);
        }

        if(isMap())
        {
            return from.join((MapAttribute<X, ?, T>) attribute, joinType);
        }

        if(isSet())
        {
            return from.join((SetAttribute<X, T>) attribute, joinType);
        }

        if(isList())
        {
            return from.join((ListAttribute<X, T>) attribute, joinType);
        }

        if(isCollection())
        {
            return from.join((CollectionAttribute<X, T>) attribute, joinType);
        }

        throw new ImpossibleException();
    }

    public Order buildOrder(CriteriaBuilderEx builder, From<?, ?> from, SortOrder direction)
    {
        if(direction == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Expression<?> expr = getExpression(builder, from);

        return direction == SortOrder.ASCENDING ? builder.asc(expr) : builder.desc(expr);
    }
}
```

with this construct, I can now safely:

```
public static List<Order> buildOrderList(CriteriaBuilderEx builder, From<?, ? extends Object> from, List<SortMeta> list)
{
    return StreamEx.of(list)
        .nonNull()
        .map(x -> buildOrder(builder, from, x.getSortField(), x.getSortOrder()))
        .nonNull()
        .toList();
}

public static Order buildOrder(CriteriaBuilderEx builder, From<?, ? extends Object> from, String path, SortOrder direction)
{
    if(path == null || path.isEmpty() || direction == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    MetaDescriptor descriptor = MetaDescriptor.getDescriptor(from, path);
    if(descriptor == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return descriptor.buildOrder(builder, from, direction);
}
```

Comment: This looks quite interesting. Can you provide `EntityUtils.getManagedType()`?

Comment: I assume orders by aggregate would still need to be handled by hand since this approach won't detect an alias like a native query would, eg: `criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.asc(builder.count(joinProject)));` .. but hey, it's still better than nothing.

Comment: see update for `EntityUtils.getManagedType()`. You assume right: it's based on metamodel (and derivates), which takes in account only plain old object (entities and embeddables) properties, using attributes - it's a _model_, indeed. Any construct, like aggregates, must be handled manually. I tried to *formalize* a way multiple times, but everytime I came up with a clumsy JPQL clone - epic fail.

Comment: @cen I forgot to put your @ in previous comment, so this is to let SO notify you :)

Comment: This works nicely. You can freely descend into the nested entities and it nicely covers 90% of all REST crud cases for me this way. Thank a lot.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes this approach fails while explicitly setting the column via metamodel works fine. This happens when the query creates two aliases for the same table, eg: `... LEFT OUTER JOIN receivers t6 ON (t6.ID = t5.receiver_id), newsletters t7, links t2, messages t1, receivers t0 
` in this case receivers is aliased to t0 and t6 at the same time. Order by is then done on t6 while group by is done on t0 causing an error (column must be in the GROUP BY ...). I'll explore this further.

Comment: @cen see update. Maybe there's some relation or a common solution.

Answer (score 1):

If sortField exists only in one entity:

```
 try{
    path = root.get(sortField);       
 }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
    path = joinProject.get(sortField);
 }

 criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(path));
```

Comment: So.. if sortField happens to be in both, a switch statement is unavoidable I assume?